# Cant figure out how to write a VBA script to sort columns by moving color to top

Tags: excel, vba

So im trying to sort a table by moving rows with red in them to the top. I'm trying to do it by column. Currently I can sort just using excel but I'd have to do several hundred columns. Here is my code so far.

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sortcol As Range
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    'Dim loopCounter As Integer
    'Dim endLoopCol
    Dim endLoopRow
    
    Set endLoopCol = 60
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table_CC400_Incoming1")
    Set endLoopRow = 1000
    
    
    
    For i = 0 To endLoopRow 'loop to sort through row
   
        For j = 1 To endLoopCol ' loop to sort through column
        
        Set sortcol = Range("Table_CC400_Incoming1[122]")
        
        With tbl.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add(Key:=sortcol, SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor) _
        .SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 153, 153)
        .Apply
    
    End With
    
    Next
    
   


End Sub
```

I'll provide some images for context since I'm terrible at explaining.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMg25.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Color is not data. These problems only come up because people color code things instead of using data that can be easily used for filtering and sorting.  Use conditional formatting to apply color based on the underlying data or some other logic. Then you can sort by that.

Comment: Add a new column, perhaps insert a new Column A and use VBA to set all values as false.  Loop through each row.  For each row, loop through each cell.  If any of the cells are red, then set Col a = True and exit for to move on to the next row.  At the end, Col A will contain a true or false.  Sort by that so that any row containing red is sorted to the top.  (If that's what you meant.)  See this useful article for additional hints: http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.CFConditions.html

Comment: @teylyn , thats how the sheet is set up already. The custom sort would work but its a couple hundred columns and constantly changing on refresh. That's why I'm trying to write a script that custom sorts columns until the end of the table.

Comment: @pghcpa thanks for the input. Wouldn't that just sort the red to the top in a random order? I'm looking to have the red cells kind of staggered down I guess. I want to look through each column starting from the left and bring any entire row with red in that column to the top. Then move to the next column and repeat. Sometimes the red cells dont start until 50+ columns in if that makes sense.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. Please edit your question, provide a simplified example that still represents all the scenarios you might run into. Mock up the desired result manually, and then explain the logic that leads to the result.

Comment: That's easy.  Use my same suggestion above but instead of setting true/false and exit for, loop through each row, then each cell and count the number of red cells in each row.  At the end of each row, put that in a new Col A, then sort Col A desc at the end.  The rows with the most number of red cells will sort to the top.  (@teylyn is a superuser and she's trying to suggest how to properly post your questions here so that you will get better help.  Although she says it doesn't make sense to her, I know what you mean.)

Comment: @pghcpa , gotcha! thanks for the help! Sorry about the confusing question, I'm new to this in general and suck at explaining things.

Comment: @pghcpa Hey man, trying to work through this right now. In theory your comment makes sense to me, but when I go to apply it I completely get lost. As I said, I'm very new to VBA, like I've been trying it for like 2 weeks. I'm really struggling with the syntax. I'm not too sure how my data being in a table should affect my code. Beyond that, I don't even know the command to get a cells RGB value haha. If you know a place I could go to get some like easy documentation that would be great cause google is giving me those really in depth stuff. Thanks!

Comment: This is a good exercise for learning VBA.  I sent you how to get the colors.  See the link in my first comment.  If I get time, I will post a sample.  But first search StackOverflow thoroughly because somewhere there is probably sample code you can use.

Comment: It would help if you followed @teylyn's advice in first comment to explain why you are sorting by color instead of using codes plus conditional formatting.  It looks like the reds are just negative numbers, so the real question is how to count the number of cells with negative numbers and sort by that?  If so, please modify your question, then you'll get more help.  On this forum, they are very particular that questions must be precise and have a logical purpose.

Comment: First answer in this post has the basic code for a user-defined function you need for your new column that counts number of negative numbers in each row.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980877/function-to-count-distinct-values-in-a-column-range